# Getting frame from soundfile

Tags: python, numpy, audio, wave

Does anyone know how I can split a sound file into frames that can then be converted into numpy arrays detailing the specific sound frequencies in the frame?

For instance, using cv2, I can split a film clip into frames that I can then store as a library of images. This code does the job nicely, to the extent I can easily get colour histograms of each image afterwards.

```
filepath1 = input('Please enter the filepath for where the frames should be saved: ') 

name = input('Please enter the name of the clip: ') 

ret, frame = clip.read()
count = 0
ret == True
while ret:
    ret, frame = clip.read()
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(filepath1,name+'%d.png'%count), frame)
    count += 1
```

But I can't seem to find anything equivalently straightforward for sound files; does anyone have any suggestions as to how (or if)it can be done?

Comment: Just to be sure - you do **not** want to create a sequence of images from a sound file, right?

Comment: Eh, yes. Because if I was looking for a sequence of images from a sound file, I'd have problems a whole lot bigger than the one posted here. I use the film example only by analogy; I want the sound file equivalent of a film frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the sound file equivalent of a film frame is an audio sample. This is just a single value per channel, so I'm not sure if that is what you really want. My best guess of what you want to achieve is to analyze how the frequency content of the file changes over time.

Maybe you want to look at a [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram)? In this case, the following script taken from [www.frank-zalkow.de](http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html?i=1) may do exactly what you want, or at least give you some ideas how to get started.
[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8
""" This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.
    Frank Zalkow, 2012-2013 """

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

""" short time fourier transform of audio signal """
def stft(sig, frameSize, overlapFac=0.5, window=np.hanning):
    win = window(frameSize)
    hopSize = int(frameSize - np.floor(overlapFac * frameSize))

    # zeros at beginning (thus center of 1st window should be for sample nr. 0)
    samples = np.append(np.zeros(np.floor(frameSize/2.0)), sig)    
    # cols for windowing
    cols = np.ceil( (len(samples) - frameSize) / float(hopSize)) + 1
    # zeros at end (thus samples can be fully covered by frames)
    samples = np.append(samples, np.zeros(frameSize))

    frames = stride_tricks.as_strided(samples, shape=(cols, frameSize), strides=(samples.strides[0]*hopSize, samples.strides[0])).copy()
    frames *= win

    return np.fft.rfft(frames)    

""" scale frequency axis logarithmically """    
def logscale_spec(spec, sr=44100, factor=20.):
    timebins, freqbins = np.shape(spec)

    scale = np.linspace(0, 1, freqbins) ** factor
    scale *= (freqbins-1)/max(scale)
    scale = np.unique(np.round(scale))

    # create spectrogram with new freq bins
    newspec = np.complex128(np.zeros([timebins, len(scale)]))
    for i in range(0, len(scale)):
        if i == len(scale)-1:
            newspec[:,i] = np.sum(spec[:,scale[i]:], axis=1)
        else:        
            newspec[:,i] = np.sum(spec[:,scale[i]:scale[i+1]], axis=1)

    # list center freq of bins
    allfreqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(freqbins*2, 1./sr)[:freqbins+1])
    freqs = []
    for i in range(0, len(scale)):
        if i == len(scale)-1:
            freqs += [np.mean(allfreqs[scale[i]:])]
        else:
            freqs += [np.mean(allfreqs[scale[i]:scale[i+1]])]

    return newspec, freqs

""" plot spectrogram"""
def plotstft(audiopath, binsize=2**10, plotpath=None, colormap="jet"):
    samplerate, samples = wav.read(audiopath)
    s = stft(samples, binsize)

    sshow, freq = logscale_spec(s, factor=1.0, sr=samplerate)
    ims = 20.*np.log10(np.abs(sshow)/10e-6) # amplitude to decibel

    timebins, freqbins = np.shape(ims)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(ims), origin="lower", aspect="auto", cmap=colormap, interpolation="none")
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.xlabel("time (s)")
    plt.ylabel("frequency (hz)")
    plt.xlim([0, timebins-1])
    plt.ylim([0, freqbins])

    xlocs = np.float32(np.linspace(0, timebins-1, 5))
    plt.xticks(xlocs, ["%.02f" % l for l in ((xlocs*len(samples)/timebins)+(0.5*binsize))/samplerate])
    ylocs = np.int16(np.round(np.linspace(0, freqbins-1, 10)))
    plt.yticks(ylocs, ["%.02f" % freq[i] for i in ylocs])

    if plotpath:
        plt.savefig(plotpath, bbox_inches="tight")
    else:
        plt.show()

    plt.clf()

plotstft("my_audio_file.wav")
```

Comment: Note, however, that the spectrogram only makes sense for a longer audio recording, but not at a single time index. What the OP probably wants to do instead is extract a short stretch of audio for each frame, and do an FFT on it which gives him the resulting frequency spectrum at that frame. The spectrum can then be plotted, or saved to a file. This [blog post](http://www.cbcity.de/die-fft-mit-python-einfach-erklaert) describes most of what is needed for this task (don't mind the first paragraph in German).

Comment: @Schmuddi That is correct. * extract a short stretch of audio for each frame, and do an FFT on it which gives him the resulting frequency spectrum at that frame* is exactly what happens in a spectrogram. Basically, each colum in the resulting image is the FFT/PSD of a "stretch" of audio.

Comment: Thanks folks; all these answers are useful, and both offer valuable (and complementary) ways of doing what I'm interested in. Now, best start getting to work with them!